# PHP unset session variable not working

Tags: php, session, unset

Problem:
I have a shopping cart. I put items in it (into session).
On checkout, I clear the `$_SESSION['order']`, and on redirect, the cart is not empty.
How ever, it's working, if I do this with a logged in user.

Comment: Maybe it could help if you show the code with the clearing and redirect

Comment: Not enough info. Wild guess... `session_start();` is not at the top of the script which serves the landing (redirected to) page  possibly, maybe , perhaps?

Comment: `// I cannot give you the whole code part :(
    // I set the $_SESSION['order'] in an other php file, and it's working fine
    session_start();
    // some long processing codeing
    if (isset($_SESSION['order'])) {
        session_start(); // <=== this has to be here to work, without it, does not works
        unset($_SESSION['order']);
        session_commit();
    }`

Comment: isset($_SESSION['order'])) { session_start(); ) doesn't make any sense for me. because the session is already set, and you are setting it again. Anyway you got it solved. :)

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['order']) : ` Saving myself from a lot of apache/error.log records :) (code cleanup)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Issuing an other session_start() before the unset solved the problem. (There's a session_start at the beginning of the php file...)
but still strange...

Comment: That's what @Duane Lortie Suggested

Comment: Yes, but I had to add an other extra session_start() before unset().